# Can I write a single command to turn WP_DEBUG or off?

Tags: wordpress

I work tech support for a hosting company that primarily uses WP and recently got cmd perms. I have found WP_DEBUG mode very helpful when figuring out whats wrong. So I have been trying to find a single line code that can go into the wp-conig.php file, and edit it to true. Can I get some help?

This is what I have so far, but it comes back with
"syntax error near unexpected token `)'"

```
sed -i 's/define( \'WP_DEBUG\', false );/define( \'WP_DEBUG\', true );/g' ~/wp-config.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own actually. the problem was just in making the sed command find "define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );". I have tried it on my own site, and seem to be working fine.

Here is the full code for those who want it. Also any advice to make it better would be appreciated. Like it wont work id debug mode isn't already there, and set to false. I can update that later.

```
sed -i "s/define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );/define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );/g" wp-config.php
sed -i "s/define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );/define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );/g" wp-config.php
```